# Cubic: Finding turning point when given x and y intercepts

Tags: cubics

[image]

I have tried substituting in the two points (-4,0) and (0,28) and solving simultaneously for b and c with no success, and the book gives two separate but equally correct solutions for b and c that satisfy the equation.

Am I looking at this the right way or can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: Can you include the exact question statement? My best guess at the statement is that there are multiple solutions, but it's impossible to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since the dilation factor is equal to $1$, the equation automatically reduces to $y=(x-b)^3+c$. Now, since the equation only has a single factor, $(x-b)$, the vector $(b,c)$ is the result we're looking for. Now, the $b$ and $c$ can be found by plugging in the given intercepts:
$$0=(-4-b)^3+c$$$$28=(-b)^3+c$$
Since this is a system of nonlinear equations, we can solve it by substitution.
$$c=-(-4-b)^3=(4+b)^3$$$$28=(-b)^3+(4+b)^3$$
Since we can't easily combine the right-hand side of this in factored form, we'll expand it.
$$28=64+48b+12b^2+b^3-b^3=64+48b+12b^2$$
Well now, that's just a simple quadratic. Solving it, we get two solutions: $(-1, 0)$ and $(-3, 0)$. Let's try plugging both of those back into the first equation:
$$c=(4-1)^3=27$$$$c=(4-3)^3=1$$
So now we have two possible coordinate pairs, $(-1, 27)$ and $(-3, 1)$. If you graph these equations, you'll see that either coordinate works.